# Azure Functions won't publish Python function

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm trying to create an Azure functions using Python code, v2 model, version 3.10.

Below are the contents of my `requirements.txt` file:

```
azure-functions
requests
beautifulsoup4
html5lib
pyjq
extruct
js2py
```

The dependency of `pyjq` has been an issue, as it doesn't want to compile when publishing the code.

If I try a local build (i.e. `--build local`), there's an issue with lxml (which is an indirect requirement):

```
There was an error restoring dependencies. 
ERROR: cannot install lxml-4.9.2 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported when building locally. 
Use the "--build remote" option to build dependencies on the Azure Functions build server,
or "--build-native-deps" option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container. 
More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish
```

As I have a local package (not available in pypi) that needs to be included as well, I decided to build wheels for both that and `pyjq` (using `pip wheel pyjq`), store them in a `wheels` subfolder and modify the `requirements.txt`:

```
<other packages>
./wheels/pyjq-2.6.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
./wheels/mypackage-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

The remote build is successful:

```
Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
Resetting all workers for fa-myapp.azurewebsites.net
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
Syncing triggers...
Functions in fa-myapp:
```

However, no functions seem to be available.

I've tested the code locally (`func host start`) and confirmed that it works.

Is there any way I can find some sort of detailed logging which will give me more information as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the use of `pyjq` package, which doesn't seem to play nice with Azure Functions. I was able to determine this by creating a new function, and adding each package one by one, publishing the function and checking the outcome. Only when adding `pyjq`, the HTTP 500 issue arose.

In the end I replaced `pyjq` with [`jello`](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jello), which has a more readable syntax (esp. if you're used to Python) and works fine with Azure Functions.